# JIRA Greenhopper - How to set the 'Flagged' custom field of type “Multi-Checkboxes” in a Workflow Transition's Post Function

Tags: workflow, transition, jira, greenhopper

In our Jira (v4.4) we are using Greenhopper (v5.7.4), as such Greenhopper makes use of the **Flagged** custom field to mark Impediments, it is of type "Multi-Checkboxes".

Whilst transitioning from one state to another we are using a pre-installed *Post Function* to try a set the Flagged custom field. Specifically we are trying the 'Set field value from User Property value' post function.

To support this 'post function' we have tried adding a transition property called **flagged**  with value **Impediment** and referencing it in the 'post function'.

This doesn't work.

Essentially 2 questions arise.

1. Is this 'post function' the best way to set a Multi-Checkbox.
2. If so, how do we specify the Impediment to be true?

For a better explanation of the default flagging behaviour see [Flagging Issues in Greenhopper](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/Flagging+an+Issue+in+GreenHopper), this is what we want to automate in our transition's 'post function'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Resolved the Issue - for those that may be looking for a similar solution - here is what I discovered, hope it helps.

Contacting Atlassian the following was suggested:

> To set the multi checkbox custom field via post-function is possible.
>   First of all, you need to install JIRA suites utility plugin:
>
> https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/5048 After that, in the
>   workflow transition, add a "Update Issue Custom Field" post function
>   with your custom field and put the flagged option (e.g. Impediment)
>   written in the "Custom Field Value" field.

So using the suggested "**Update Issue Custom Field**" post function I chose the **Flagged** custom field and used the value '**Impediment**' on its own. This worked.

For another transition that unmarked the impediment I used the "Clear Field Value Function" and simple chose the "Flagged" field. This also worked at clearing the Impediment.